# How can I change icon in the KeyboardTimePicker (material-ui-pickers)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I can't change the icon in the `KeyboardTimePicker`. I read about the `KeyboardButtonProps` and `InputAdornmentProps` but I don't understand how can it help me...

[my KeyboardTimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRill.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for keyboard icon there was created new prop : `keyboardIcon`

```
import Favorite from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite'
...
<KeyboardTimePicker
   label="Masked timepicker"
   placeholder="08:00 AM"
   mask="__:__ _M"
   value={selectedDate}
   onChange={handleDateChange}
   keyboardIcon={<Favorite />}
/>
```

Comment: i am glad to help you @АннаЧаплыгина . Please mark this answer as accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: If you don't want to use the icon keyboardIcon={false}